# right side scroll bar is not showing in chrome for my wordpress website.. its working well in firefox and other browser

Tags: php, wordpress

Recently i was working on a WordPress theme. After instilling theme website is working well in all browser. 
the problem is right scroll bar is not showing in chrome browser rather its working well in Firefox and other browsers. 
only chrome is creating problem for my website. 
there is a no issue of browser because in all other websites chrome is showing scroll bar well.
thanks in advance.

Comment: share your website URL

Comment: http://www.davidjpphillips.com/  i am on windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the following line

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none 
 }
```

from you style.css file. Path http://www.davidjpphillips.com/wp-content/themes/davidphillips/style.css

Comment: oh that was my mistake.. thanks a lot.. https://stackoverflow.com/users/3977580/dev-kiran